# Cant Remove a backslash from string using regex in .net

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to remove illegal chars from a string that represent path or filename in windows.

Here is the code i used for testing:

```cs
        string pattern = "([\", \\, <,>, :, /, ?,|,*])";
        string[] names = { "o\"ne", "t\\wo", "thr<ee", "fo>ur", "fi:ve", "si/x", "sev?en", "ei|ght", "ni*ne" };
        foreach (String name in names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(name, pattern, String.Empty));
        }
```

I get all prints okay, except "two" that writes like this: t\wo.
I've tried putting an asterisk outside the parenthesis and got the same result.

What should i do?

Thank You.

Comment: You might want to check out `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()`

Comment: How do i use it as a pattern for regex?

Comment: This is not really meant to be used for regex; it could be used by manually replacing the illegal chars.

Comment: There's also `Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` that's a little closer to your case

Comment: are there different chars for illegl path and file name?

Comment: Yes, filenames cannot contain path separators (\ or /)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to double escape the backslash in your regex pattern; the reason being that the backslash character is used to indicate character groups in regexes (e.g., `\d` to represent digits). To match on a backslash, you use the notation `\\`. This then has to be escaped in the .NET string.

In short, change `\\` to `\\\\`.